How to implement authentication of users in ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API using LDAP
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project. This project acts as a gateway, accepts the content of the front-end request, and forwards the content to different microservices.
I want to integrate a LDAP authentication. How do I do it? Is there an example for me to refer to? What class library should I use to integrate it?
This project is deployed with docker and will be deployed in a linux environment. So which package should I use to integrate it? What should be configured in the appsettings.json file? What should be registered in the Program.cs file?
I want to verify whether the user exists in the LDAP server when logging in to the interface.
I don't know what library to use and what the whole process is. I hope someone can provide me with an example. Thank you.

LDAP is oauth2.0 flow. I used to see a sample use AzureAD package to connect and wowks.

I want to know when i use  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement library , it is work in every ldap server?
